# howto specify requirements for external packages/executables in python project

Tags: python

I'd like to know if it's possible to specify requirements for external non-python packages/executables via setuptools or a like.

Thanks.

Comment: @Blender, I noticed that one, but what I'm looking is how to require non-python packages, e.g. any package from ppa or availability of executable/*.so/etc. via setuptools. So, I can run setup.py or pip install FooBar and get notice if some executable missed.

Comment: ...just looking if there is common approach :)